# Can I use LXD image to create Docker container and/or vice versa?

Tags: image, docker, lxc, lxd

A container system making use of LXC containers.

the above statement is true for both LXD and Docker. In that case can we use LXD image to create Docker container and/or vice versa?

Answer (score 3):

They are fundamentally different.

With LXD container image you get full OS experience, it means all applications and processes that are part of the distro, only kernel is shared with the host. With Docker image you get single process application.

So you can have Docker running inside LXD container, but not the other way around.

The confusion might arise from the fact that Docker did use liblxc library in the past, that LXD daemon is using to control containers. If I understand correctly Docker is using another library called libcontainer now to provide isolation.

Comment: Does it answer your question?